# Using data from first mysqli query in second query and nesting results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have multiple tables I am joining to use in results for a second query and nesting the second results inside the first results.

I am using the following code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT info.lotto_id, info.name, info.number_balls, info.number_bonus_balls, info.db_name, country.name_eng AS country, currency.name AS currency, currency.symbol AS symbol, next.draw_date AS next_draw, next.jackpot AS next_jackpot
FROM info
LEFT JOIN country ON info.country_id = country.id_country 
LEFT JOIN currency ON info.currency_id = currency.currency_id
LEFT JOIN next ON info.lotto_id = next.lotto_id
WHERE (info.active='1')
ORDER BY next_jackpot DESC");

while($lotto = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{

    echo "<table border='0' width='600px' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<h1>Results for:</h1>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td align='right'>";
    echo "<p><img src='images/". $lotto['lotto_id'] ."_big.png' alt='". $lotto['name'] ." Results'/></p>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM" .$lotto['db_name'].
"ORDER BY date DESC
Limit 3");

while($draw = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))

  {
    echo "<table class='results' align='center'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    $draw['display_date'] = strtotime($draw['date']);
$lotto['cols'] = $lotto['number_balls'] + $lotto['number_bonus_balls'];
    echo "<td class='date' colspan='".$lotto['cols']."'>".date('D M d, Y', $draw['display_date']). "</td>";

if ($draw[jp_code] < "1")
{
    echo "<td class='winner' align='center'>Jackpot Amount</td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td class='rollover' align='center'>Rollover Amount</td>";
}
```

It is giving me the following error: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/95/11798395/html/results/info_mysqli.php on line 59

This relates to my results2 query. Can somebody please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: I suspect you need to add spaces in your second query around the table name. But you should be able to see exactly what the problem is by checking the return value of `mysqli_query()`, and looking at `mysqli_error()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM" .$lotto['db_name'].
"ORDER BY date DESC
Limit 3");
```

to:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM {$lotto['db_name']} ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3");
if ($result === false) {
    exit("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}
```